# PC cannot access HC-06 Bluetooth COM port

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, bluetooth

I have an HC-06 Bluetooth module connected to an Arduino Uno board to allow for the data received by the Ultrasonic sensor to be transferred to my PC via Bluetooth and serial communication.

I am using the PuTTY program to view the data. The thing is, my PC says that it has paired with the Bluetooth and I was able to see the COM number, but when I opened PuTTY and entered the COM number while choosing the option 'serial' an error box appeared saying: "Unable to open serial port."

The way I am currently connecting my b
Bluetooth to the arduino board is:

RX->pin 10
TX->pin 11
GND->GND pin
VCC-> 5V VCC

I am sure that the sketch in the Arduino for serial communication via Bluetooth is right as I have tested the system yesterday and it worked.

Only after a time (say like 5-10 min) the connection breaks and I can't seem to figure out the problem. The Arduino is being powered by USB, if that matters.

Comment: If you have powered the BT module from 5v you may have fried it, I recall that the hc-06 module is 3.3v and 3.3v signal too.

Comment: The HC-06 vcc needs minimum power 3.6 to 6V, but it's the rx, tx pins that need 3.3 v output from the arduino